Is it possible to explicitly say “the restaurant that I'm eating” in Japanese?
The reason I ask this rather curious question is because I remember someone once saying something along the lines of:

“私が食べているレストラン” means “The restaurant in which I'm eating" not, “the restaurant that I'm eating”, unless the speaker would be Godzilla, then it can mean that.

The issue obviously being that unlike in English, Japanese mostly uses context to resolve the grammatical role of the modified noun in the relative clause whereas English uses relative pronouns to explicitly make this role clear. I know the opposite is possible and we can for instance use “私が中で食べている食べ物” to explicitly say “The food in which I'm eating” as “私が食べている食べ物” would, despite sharing the same grammar with the above example, surely be construed as “the food that I'm eating” but I don't know if it's possible to invert it. If we wish to be explicit for instance, could we say “私がそのレストランを食べているレストラン”? What of “私がそれを食べているレストラン”.
The example is obviously by design nonsensical because if it were sensible context would automatically resolve it.

I'd say this is less about the (mis)conception that "Japanese mostly uses context" or that Japanese is particularly more context-dependent than other languages. This is about how relative clauses work in Japanese. Relative clauses work differently in every language and English has its own idiosyncrasies when it comes to relative clauses. To give you an example: "This is a place you can relax" "That is a place I wanna live". You don't relax a place; nor can you live a place. But that's how English works.

If you need to explicitly convey restaurant-as-food in a few words, possible options are:

私がレストランを食べる、そのレストラン
私が食べる対象のレストラン (this is still a little ambiguous)
私が餌として食べるレストラン

Similar examples:

寿司を食べるスーツを着た男
a man in a suit eating sushi
(there is only one reasonable interpretation, but technically ambiguous)
寿司を食べるスーツ、それを着た男
a man in a sushi-eating suit
私があげる人
the person I'm giving it to
私が人をあげる、その人
私があなたにあげる人
私がプレゼントとしてあげる人
the person I'm giving to you


I think in particular the “餌として” solution is both intuitive and clear.

Both of your examples do not make sense.

私がそのレストランを食べているレストラン


私がそれを食べているレストラン

are both ungrammatical.
I feel like "私が食べているレストラン" is also pretty unnatural. Most Japanese people would understand what you mean and probably say this sometimes, but without a doubt, a more natural way of saying this would be with the verb 食事をする instead of 食べる. Some Japanese pedants (including some of my friends) would even default to the "Godzilla" interpretation if they heard "私が食べているレストラン". They would insist that the direct object of 食べる can only be what you ate and never where you ate.
This leads me to believe that the best way to clear up your dilemma is to observe the difference between

私が食事をしているレストラン


私が食べているレストラン

which, in a vacuum context (without any indication that Godzilla is in the picture) would carry the same meaning, but the distinction would become immediately clear in any context where it is known that you can literally eat a restaurant.
Side note, "私が中で食べている食べ物" is also unnatural unless your 中 here means "レストランの中". However, if such clarification is even necessary I would say "私が(レストラン/そこ)で食べている食べ物" sans the の中 would be a much clearer choice of words.

With 私が中で食べている食べ物 I think @zorf intended to provide a silly example. Imagine sitting inside a giant bread roll while eating your dinner, for example.
